# Separate output for each iteration

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
def calculate_average_grade(grades_dictionary):
        grades_avg = {}
        for key in grades_dictionary.keys():
                average = sum(grades_dictionary[key]) / len(grades_dictionary[key])
                grades_avg[key] = average
        return grades_avg
grades_dictionary = readGrade
avg_grade = calculate_average_grade(grades_dictionary)
print(f' {readGrade} => {avg_grade}')
```

I need this code to print output separately like `{"XYZ": [3,2,4,5]}  ==>   {"XYZ": 3.5}`

My code outputs together like-

```
{'PQR': [4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 3.5], 'LMN': [4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5]}) => {'PQR': 3.8333333333333335, 'LMN': 3.4166666666666665}
```

Comment: This should include the grades_dictionary input in the code block. Are you looking for something similar to for name in avg_grade: print (name, grades_dictionary[name], avg_grade[name])

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your code. Make a function that computes averages, and run that in a loop that prints averages. The alternative would be to turn your function into a generator, and run that in a loop, but that would just make it unnecessarily complicated.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
def calculate_average_grade(grades):
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)

for key, grades in readGrade.items():
    print(f'{{{key!r}: {grades}}} => {{{key!r}: {calculate_average_grade(grades)}}}')
```

When you have an f-string, curly braces that you want to print literally have to be escaped by doubling them up. If you want quotes around a string in the format, print it using `repr` instead of `str`, by using the `!r` specifier.

With this formulation, you keep the formatting and the computation separate in your code, making at least the latter reusable, since it's not tied to a particular data format.

Comment: Good. This might be more readable with for key, grades in readGrade.items() This also avoids calculate_average_grade function needing to know about another data structure, if you just pass it an iterable.

Comment: @KennyOstrom. This is meant more as an illustration of a way of thinking than a "best approach". It's always an exercise for the reader to figure out how to use the given info. In some cases it might be better to have a more generic average that operates on a sequence, in others it might require additional information about the data. I think there's significant merit to your suggestion

Comment: Yes, I said I liked it. Now, practice what you preach: make a function that computes averages. It doesn't need a dictionary or a key, because you already have just the grades.

Comment: @KennyOstrom. I did